# SVG <use> internally

Tags: html, svg

I cannot get SVG `use` to work internal to itself.

I can get SVG `use` to work for external references.

This works:

```
<svg>
 <defs>
    <symbol id = "foo">
       <some svg stuff>
    </symbol>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

**HTML**

```
<svg><use xlink:href="my.svg#foo"/></svg>
```

However I want to re-use symbols internally in the SVG. So this doesn't work:

```
<svg>
 <defs>
    <symbol id = "foo">
       <some svg stuff>
    </symbol>
 </defs>
 <g id = "foo-bar">
    <use xlink:href="#foo"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

**HTML**

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#my.svgfoo-bar"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` does work internally. Look at this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/0o4jtntL/

As you can see, there is only one caveat: the defined symbol can be croped before being used. So be sure that this symbol is drawn at the center of your screen when you define it.

```
<svg>
 <defs>
    <symbol id = "foo">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red" stroke="black"/>
    </symbol>
 </defs>
 <g id = "foo-bar">
    <use x="20" y="20" xlink:href="#foo"/>
    <use x="0" y="50" xlink:href="#foo"/>
    <use x="40" y="10" xlink:href="#foo"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I cannot access foo-bar in an HTML page if the SVG file is external. Example, I can do this in my HTML page: `'<svg><use xlink:href="mySvg.svg#foo" /></svg>'` But I cannot do `'<svg><use xlink:href="mySvg.svg#foo-bar" /></svg>'` - Nothing shows up! If I load the SVG in FireFox I see #foo-bar. It seems that something gets lost when I try to use <use> in HTML that points to an SVG id that also uses <use>